# Adding javax.mail dependency jar to intellij library through gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I need to include the mail-1.4.7 jar file into my intellij idea project library through gradle build. I added the compile repository name into my build.gradle file as below:

compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'

Then i ran my build and although there is no error during the build, i am unable to see the jar in my project library. I was thinking through the gradle build, the jar will be managed automatically. Not sure if i need to try something else. I also tried running gradle :cleanIdea but without success.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally i was able to resolve this. I reverted all changes to start again. Followed the below steps:

1. Add `compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'` to dependencies in `build.gradle` file.
2. Run `gradle build` which will download the jar file to put in the repositories.
3. Run `gradle cleanIdea`
4. Run `gradle idea`

This resolved all the problems with the `cleanidea` clearing the iml files for intellij and regenerating through `gradle idea` command.

Comment: Artifact `javax.mail-api` of group `javax.mail` was moved to `javax.mail-api` in the meanwhile, so it should be: `implementation 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2'`

Comment: compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
this work for me